# Problem with CSS3 Loading Spinners without image

Tags: css

I don't have too much experience with CSS. I've created a HTML5 web app. To show some loading activity in page, I used CSS from this blog: [CSS3 loading spinners without images](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/css-xhtml/css3-loading-spinners-without-images/). Author showed how it is possible to create loading screen without any images. I used exact CSS3 code with some extra divs. But somehow one of the bars is not properly aligned when used inside my page. I get progress bar as shown in below image:

[image: Spinner]

And CSS & HTML is as below:

```
<div id="mainSpinnerDiv_aims">
<div id="spinnerDiv_aims">
  <div class="bar1_aims"></div>
  <div class="bar2_aims"></div>
  <div class="bar3_aims"></div>
  <div class="bar4_aims"></div>
  <div class="bar5_aims"></div>
  <div class="bar6_aims"></div>
  <div class="bar7_aims"></div>
  <div class="bar8_aims"></div>
</div>  
<p id="waitText_aims"> please wait...   </p>    
 </div> 


.bar1_aims {
   -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) translate(0, -40px);opacity:0.12;
 }
.bar2_aims {
   -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg) translate(0, -40px);opacity:0.25;
 }
.bar3_aims {
   -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg) translate(0, -40px);opacity:0.37;
 }
.bar4_aims {
   -webkit-transform:rotate(135deg) translate(0, -40px);opacity:0.50;
 }
.bar5_aims {
   -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg) translate(0, -40px);opacity:0.62;
 }
.bar6_aims {
   -webkit-transform:rotate(225deg) translate(0, -40px);opacity:0.75;
 }
.bar7_aims {
   -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg) translate(0, -40px);opacity:0.87;
 }
.bar8_aims {
   -webkit-transform:rotate(315deg) translate(0, -40px);opacity:1;
 }


#mainSpinnerDiv_aims{
margin-top:70px;
width: 100%;
text-align:center;
}

#spinnerDiv_aims{
    position:relative; 
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation-name: rotateSpinner;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1.3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
}

#waitText_aims {
font-weight:600;
}

#spinnerDiv_aims div{
width:10px;
height:30px;
background:#a00;
position:absolute;
top:35px;
left:45px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateSpinner {
   from {-webkit-transform:scale(0.25) rotate(0deg);}
   to {-webkit-transform:scale(0.25) rotate(360deg);}
}
```

**Note that "bar1" is the one which is not properly aligned in above figure.**

**Edit:**

Thanks everyone for quick response. Finally I figured out the problem. It turns out that I had some comment right before .bar1_aims { } style. It was not properly commented. That's why only bar1 was messed up. It is now solved.

Comment: @Joseph  My bad. I removed '; from post. It was working for me as well. But somehow it has stopped working and I get spinner as I've shown above.

Comment: It's chrome. It works in jsFiddle. But when used with my page it doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like it has to do with the rest of the page or some kind of styling rule conflicting

Comment: @indusBull: I don't suppose you have any `div:first-of-type` selectors or similar?

Comment: I also suspect conflicting. But can't figure it out. Will try again.

Comment: This works fine for me too, in Chrome, as @Joseph says. Have you looked at it again? Or tried isolating it - make a document that's as simple as possible containing just this code, and then gradually add in all your other stuff and see what breaks it.

Comment: Please check my edit in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the use of CSS over images to reduce HTTP requests and improve performance, but replacing a small animated .gif file with a series of divs which are constantly running javascript functions to animate seems pointless.

It seems ironic considering it will only be used while waiting for something else to load.

---

Therefore my answer would be to generate a .gif image on [Ajax Load](http://www.ajaxload.info/) and replace your code with the following:

```
<img src="/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
```

Comment: not to mention it doesn't work in FF, Opera, or IE (at least < 9) :S

Comment: Madness. It's nice to show the power of CSS3, but I can't think of a situation when I'd use this over an animated image (which will always be cross-browser compatible)

Comment: Unfortunately that is very true... and just thinking of how long it has taken MS to pull support for IE6 is rather depressing.  We're in for a long wait before the majority of in-home computes will support this.

Comment: Replacing gradient images with CSS, fair enough. Replacing animated images with CSS3 and Javascript, just opens another can of worms!

Comment: @Curt Thanks for your comments. There is a reason for using CSS3 based on our requirement. I won't go in more details. And I am not targeting cross-browsers.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think what may be causing your problem is the markup.  It has weird `';`s everywhere.</strike>  The actual code seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/87Rbs/

Comment: Works fine for me as well. Are you using Chrome or Safari? Maybe @indusBull is using whatever we aren't...

Comment: @josh he's using chrome.  See his comment on the main question